# Recovering a project?

Tags: xcode, git, recovery

So... how to recover a project? I recently changed the name all over the place and it was working properly. Today I stashed changes and committed, a popup appeared stating some file needed to be saved again and I did.

After this, the project doesn't open with this error:

`Project /Users/{User}/Desktop/Proyectos/To Battle!/To Battle! BACKUP.xcodeproj cannot be opened because it is missing its project.pbxproj file.`

What's worse is that the files I had open on Xcode and was editing, and compiled, and worked are nowhere to be found. Not on my comp, not on my iCloud Drive, nowhere. Ran a `find /` with some name of the files and there are results on `/Users/{User}/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Battle_Plan-fmoltogzcytatsanjtyvicdzzcjk/Index/DataStore` which is the old name of the project

And here: `/Users/{User}/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/To_Battle!-cgasouaduxuosbbpbnuqcrgkxump/Build/Intermediates.noindex/To Battle!.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/To Battle! (iOS).build/Objects-normal/arm64`
which contains all my files in different formats: `.d`, `.o`, `.dia`, `.swiftdepts` and looks like the compiled code of my test runs on the simulator

So, any ideas on how to recover the project? I also had made a git stash and commit for the changes before everything broke...

Comment: Note that there is never any reason to rename your project, as it is not user-facing. Moreover, renaming the project is dangerous. Moreover, renaming a project to have a space or an exclamation mark in the name will almost certainly break the project.

Comment: Moreover, "not on my iCloud Drive" is also a bad smell. Never put a git repository on iCloud Drive or any other network-sharing system such as DropBox, as it will destroy your repository and you will lose your data.

Comment: You know, this doesn't really help me or anyone that comes with the question... How are your comments helping find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Create a new git branch from the last commit you made before everything broke.

1. Press Cmd-2 in Xcode to open the source control navigator.
2. Select the current branch from the source control navigator to see all the commits you made on that branch.
3. Select the last commit you made before everything broke and right-click.
4. Choose New Branch from.
5. Name the new branch.
6. Select the branch you created from the source control navigator and right-click.
7. Choose Check Out.

Now your project is where it was before everything broke.

The source control navigator has a Stashed Changes folder. Your stashes should be in that folder.

Comment: Managed to do this, but the project is on a different state... its like the files were never there on the first place, which is impossible because they were built and ran on the simulator...

Comment: Edit your question and provide more details on what you did after you renamed the project. What files did you add to the project? What git operations did you perform? Did you commit the newly added files to the git repo? Is your git repo remotely hosted somewhere, like GitHub? What files that should be in the repo are missing after branching from the last stable commit? No one can solve your problem without the additional information and details. If you followed my instructions, your project should be where it was before you renamed it.

Comment: The thing is, to me, it looks like after renaming the project, something went wrong on the folder on which the files were being stored and they weren't being saved properly, which is why I cannot find them when running a `find`.  And this is why the repo clones into the same state with the files "hidden" on those folders, but I'm not able to see them. Anyway since I didn't advance much, I recoded the whole project again because I figured it would be faster to start over than trying to recover it. Thanks anyway!